# Inversely proportional score based on profit margins

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My question might be pretty simple but I'm having a hard time to solve it.

I'm trying to create a score based on companies profit margins.
The lower the profit margins, the higher the score. That includes negative numbers (let's say -10% profit margin should have a larger score than 10% profit margins.

Score 1 = -100% profit margin

Score 0 = +100% profit margin

What equation should I use?

Comment: I think that you just want a simple linear equation. You want to lineally interpolate between (-100,1) and (100,0). Take a look at this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points

Comment: However, this might change depending on how fast you want the score to decline as profit margin increases. There are a lot of other ways of putting a curve between the points (-100,1) and (100,0). If you want score to decrease the same amount for any increase in profit margin, linear interpolation should/linear equations should be fine.